# How to dynamically generate $LocalHostName value rsyslog

Tags: configuration, syslog, rsyslog

I have set up a central remote syslog server where I am sending all my logs. There will be many machines logging to the syslog server. On the client machine, in the rsyslog.conf I am trying to modify the host name. I know I can use the following to change the loggers host name.

```
$LocalHostName foo
```

However I want to be able to able to dynamically modify the Local hostname based on some environment variable.

```
if [[ -z $FOO ]]; then 
    $LocalHostName "$FOO foo"
else 
    $LocalHostName "$FOO foo"
 fi
```

rsyslog take the literal string `"$FOO foo"` as the new hostname.

I also have the option of writing a script that can modify the rsyslog.conf file and updates the localhostname value. However is there some way to dynamically generate hostnames in rsyslog?